# Can we go back from Blaze plan to the Spark plan?

Tags: firebase

Is it possible to switch back to the Spark (free) plan once upgrading to the Blaze (pay as you go) plan?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about payment plan details and should really be directed at Firebase customer support.

Answer (score 11):

Yes you can,
just click on tne **modify** button in the console and it shows you your plan.
Then you can select any plan you like whether to upgrade or downgrade your plan.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you are not required to stay on Blaze.  When you click the "modify" button at the bottom left of the console when it shows your plan, you will be able to select any other plan.